# how to convert json to list/map with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I encountered a piece of json as below:

```json
{
  "code": 1,
  "msg": "query success",
  "obj": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "value": {
          "num": "89"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "1",
        "value": {
          "num": "19"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "2",
        "value": {
          "num": "6"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "success": true,
  "duration": 523
}
```

I need `name` and `num`. How to convert it to a list of java.util.List<HashMap<String, String>> with Jackson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jackson `ObjectMapper` with `TypeReference` ,
First you need to read it as Map<String,Object> then you can extract the name and num with Java.

you need to get the `data` from `obj` then for each item in the dataList you have to map it to a new `HashMap` as shown below

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper ();
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData,new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
List<Object> data = ((Map<String,Object>)jsonMap.get("obj")).get("data");
List<Map<String,String> result = data.stream()
   .map(d->(Map<String,Object> d)
   .map(d->{
      Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
      map.put(d.get("name"),((Map<String,String>)d.get("value")).get("num"));
      return map;
      })
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However if you can create a `class` for the the data it will be bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Library *Josson* can do the job.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"code\": 1," +
    "  \"msg\": \"query success\"," +
    "  \"obj\": {" +
    "    \"data\": [" +
    "      {" +
    "        \"name\": \"\"," +
    "        \"value\": {" +
    "          \"num\": \"89\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      }," +
    "      {" +
    "        \"name\": \"1\"," +
    "        \"value\": {" +
    "          \"num\": \"19\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      }," +
    "      {" +
    "        \"name\": \"2\"," +
    "        \"value\": {" +
    "          \"num\": \"6\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      }" +
    "    ]" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"success\": true," +
    "  \"duration\": 523" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("obj.data.map(name::value.num)");
System.out.println(node);

List<Map<String, String>> result = Josson.readValueFor(node, List.class);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
[{"":"89"},{"1":"19"},{"2":"6"}]

[{=89}, {1=19}, {2=6}]
```